# How to prevent user from entering zero as an input?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I'm trying to add input validation to a set of three `EditTexts`, that the user enters numeric values into.
The problem I'm facing is for the calculation to work the user can't enter zero as one of the input fields or the application will crash.

I tried to implement the following to prevent zero from being entered and show a warning message. I get an error stating "unable to start activity calcResult" which is the activity that shows the calculation.

This is the link to the error log: http://pastebin.com/hDsabjR6

I understand from this that the zero value is still slipping through the validation but I don't know why?

```
 String getoffsetlength = offsetLength.getText().toString(); 

 if (getoffsetlength.trim().equals('0')) {

     Toast.makeText(this, "Enter number greater than 0!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     return;
   }
```

The application crashes when I have used this validation in the app. Any ideas as to where I have messed up with this implementation?

Comment: Will you please post the error log

Comment: okay I will post it now.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hDsabjR6

Comment: @BrianJ you can just use if(getoffsetlength.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0") I have posted the answer down below too.

Comment: why not convert the string to an int and check if it is equal to 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `android:digits="123456789"` to the `EditText` in XML. This way the user won't be able to input `0`

[EDIT]

However, if you want to avoid the user from entering `0` only at the beginning, then use this:

```
code_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                if (code_text.getText().toString().matches("^0") )
                {
                    // Not allowed
                    Toast.makeText(context, "not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    code_text.setText("");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) { }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        });
```

Comment: will that work if a user want to enter for example "20" .Will this exclude the user being able to enter a value with zero in it? My aim is to allow the user enter any numeric value except for a blank or 0

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
if(getoffsetlength.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("0"){
 Toast.makeText(this, "Enter number greater than 0!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could acheive through `EditText's` `doOnTextChanged` listener in `Kotlin`

```
editText.doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ ->
       if(text?.length == 2 && text.get(0).toString() == "0") {
            setText("0")
            setSelection(1)
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below code

```
        int PreviousLen;
        boolean keyDel; 
        etActLoginMobNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            mPreviousLen = s.length();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            keyDel = mPreviousLen > s.length();
            if(!keyDel){
                if (etActLoginMobNo.getText().toString().startsWith("0")) {
                    etActLoginMobNo.setText("");
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enter_mobile_no_without_zero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
```