# Android: Edittext that only allows a digit from 1-9

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am looking for a way so that users can only input a number between 1-9 with edittext. No exception should be displayed. It should not be possible to type in more than one digit.

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problems have you encountered?

Comment: `android:digits="123456789"
android:inputType="number"`

Comment: Have you tried any others answers to search? It has already answers.Be ware of duplicate questions to support community.That one can help you. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248674/how-to-prevent-user-from-entering-zero-as-an-input/20248774#20248774

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EditText view with keyboard number only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817521/edittext-view-with-keyboard-number-only)

Comment: I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ther have two ways for your question
1) in your XML fayl

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edittext"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:digits="123456789"
  android:inputType="number"
  android:maxLength="1"/>
```

2) in your Activity class

```
    mEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );
    mEdit.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
    mEdit.setSingleLine(true);
```

Comment: mEdit.setSingleLine(true) is not working for setting the limit to just one digit, so you must use a filter in order to achieve this.

Comment: @JoseRicardoCiterioAlcala I agree, I tried all the other solutions and finally achieved it. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359564/2462531)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the input type programmatically like this :-

```html
 
myEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
myEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("123456789"));
InputFilter[] inputArray = new InputFilter[1];
inputArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(1);
myEditText.setFilters(inputArray);
```

or you can set the XML attributes like this :-

```html
 android:inputType="number"
 android:digits="123456789"
 android:maxLength="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use attribute `android:inputType="number"` to take `input` only number `0-9`

**2.** Use attribute `android:digits="123456789"` to take only `1-9`

**3.** Use attribute `android:maxLength="1"` to allow user to input only a  single `digit`.

**Try this:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="123456789"
    android:maxLength="1"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

> try this way

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="123456789"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:inputType="number" />
```