# How to check first character non zero in android studio Edittext?

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

This is my code. I want to check if the first caharacter is 0 or not, If first character is zero, then it should say that it is not a valid number, There are no errors but is 'charAt' does not work in Android Studio?

public boolean validateAccnum() {
            boolean valid = true;

```
        if (account.isEmpty()) {
            s_acc.setError("Account number is required");
            valid = false;
        } else if (account.charAt(0)== 0){
                s_acc.setError("Not a valid number");
                valid = false;
        }else{
            s_acc.setError(null);
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors, It simply does not check validity!!, charAt()

Comment: I hope you may get help from below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72729918/12313041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Like this

```
    val account= "0123"
    if (account.get(0).equals("0"))
    {
            s_acc.setError("Not a valid number");
            valid = false;
    }
```